# how to use input$dateRange[1] and input$dateRange[2] out of renderfunction in R shiny?

Tags: r, shiny

i want to use input$dateRange[1] and input$dateRange[1] in a function that request data from a database in my company .the function i am using belongs to a package that belongs to my firm but it is that complicated it is built over sql and c (stuff like that).when i launch my app i get the following error :

```
Warning: Error in wmq_find: object 'input' not found
  50: wmq_find
Error in wmq_find(progb = "FCM", from = input$dateRange[1], to = input$dateRange[2],  : 
  object 'input' not found
```

below is a litte bite of code used in the UI und then you can find a chunk of code used ih the server:

```
  sidebar = dashboardSidebar(
    collapsed = FALSE,
    width = 290,
    sidebarMenu(
    menuItem("Summary",tabName = "Summary") ,  
  
   dateRangeInput('dateRange',
                  label = 'Filter  by date',

                  start = "2021-09-14" , end = "2021-09-21"

)
```

and then:

```
myd1<- wmq_find(progb = "FCM",from = input$dateRange[1]  ,to= input$dateRange[2],verbose = T, dbLocation = "erfurt", outMode = "outh",maptype =  "cmap")
```

New code:

```
 myda1<- eventReactive(input$update, {
    # paste("From:", input$dateRange[1], "to:", input$dateRange[2])
      wmq_find(
      progb = "FCM",
      from = paste(input$dateRange[1]),
      to = paste(input$dateRange[2]),
      verbose = T,
      dbLocation = "erfurt",
      outMode = "outh",
      maptype =  "cmap"
    )})
 mergeddata<-reactive({
   
    myd1<-myda1()[ !duplicated(myda1()[, c("wafer_Id", "date","time")], fromLast=T),]
    myd1<-myd1[,c(4,5,7,9,11,18,20,21)]
    myd1$Lot_Wf <- paste(myd1$lot_Id, myd1$wafer_Id,sep="/")
    colnames(myd1)<-c("Lot","Wafer","M_Datum","Messprogramm","Device","Total","Pass","Yield","Lot/Wf")
    myd1$M_Datum<-as.Date(myd1$M_Datum,format="%d.%m.%y")
    myd1<-unique(myd1)
    myd1$Device<-gsub(" ","",myd1$Device)
    myd1$Lot<-gsub(" ","",myd1$Lot)
    myd1$Yield<-suppressWarnings(as.numeric(myd1$Yield))
    myd1$Messprogramm<-gsub(" ","",myd1$Messprogramm)
    myd1<-myd1[myd1$Messprogramm=="FCM_ERF",]
    mergeddata<-merge(myd1,mydonee,by="Device")
    #dte[,4]<-strftime(dte[,4], format = '%Y-%m-%d %R')
   # dte[,4]<-as.Date(substr(dte[,4],0,10),"%Y-%m-%d")
    colnames(mergeddata)<-gsub(" ","_",colnames( mergeddata))
    colnames( mergeddata)<-gsub("-","_",colnames( mergeddata))
    return( mergeddata)
    
  })
 res_mod <- callModule(
    module = selectizeGroupServer,
    id = "m",
    data =  mergeddata,
    vars = c("Device","MEMS_flag","Process_Family","Local_Process_id","Customer_Name"),
    inline=FALSE
    
  )
  
  output$table <- renderDataTable({
    input$update
    
    dato<-res_mod() 
    
    return(dato) },
     
    options = list(scrollX = TRUE))
```

Comment: It seems that you are trying to access those inputs outside of the server function - which won't work.

Comment: @ismirsehregal what does this mean? can you futher develop your "solution"?

Comment: It means what I wrote - you can access `input$dateRange[1]` only inside the server function: `server <- function(input, output, session) {<<only here>>}`. But that's just a guess as youn didn't share a reproducible example.

Comment: @ismirsehregal the problem is that when i do like that i get the following:   Warning: Error in $: Can't access reactive value 'dateRange' outside of reactive consumer.
i Do you need to wrap inside reactive() or observe()?
  54: <Anonymous>
Error in input$dateRange : 
  Can't access reactive value 'dateRange' outside of reactive consumer.
i Do you need to wrap inside reactive() or observe()?

Comment: Exactly - you'll need a `reactive` context inside the server function. Can be for example `reactive`, `observe` or `isolate` depending on your use case. Maybe you start with `observeEvent` to trigger your function on a `actionButton` click.

Comment: @ismirsehregal the problem is that i already used a reactive wrap for both date bounds but it doesn´t work.

Comment: @ismirsehregal iget the same error when i use the following code:  a<-reactive({a<-input$dateRange[1]})
   
   b<-reactive({a<-input$dateRange[2]})
  
  myd1<- wmq_find(progb = "FCM",from =a()   ,to= b(),verbose = T, dbLocation = "erfurt", outMode = "outh",maptype =  "cmap")

Comment: I left some example code below.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the following:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(DT)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(),
  dashboardSidebar(
    collapsed = FALSE,
    width = 290,
    sidebarMenu(
      menuItem("Summary", tabName = "Summary"),
      dateRangeInput(
        'dateRange',
        label = 'Filter by date',
        start = "2021-09-14",
        end = "2021-09-21"
      ),
      actionButton(
        inputId = "update",
        label = "Update Data",
        icon = icon("arrows-rotate"),
        width = "260px"
      )
    )
  ),
  dashboardBody(DTOutput("my_table"))
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  dummyDF <- data.frame(date = seq(from = as.Date("2021-09-14"), to = as.Date("2021-09-21"), "days"), value = 1:8)
  
  myd1 <- eventReactive(input$update, {
    dummyDF[dummyDF$date >= min(as.Date(input$dateRange)) & dummyDF$date <= max(as.Date(input$dateRange)),]
    # wmq_find(
    #   progb = "FCM",
    #   from = input$dateRange[1],
    #   to = input$dateRange[2],
    #   verbose = T,
    #   dbLocation = "erfurt",
    #   outMode = "outh",
    #   maptype =  "cmap"
    # )
  })
  
  output$my_table <- renderDT({
    myd1()
  }, server = FALSE)
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: i get this: Warning: Error in if: missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed

Comment: Try replacing your code with `datasets::iris`. The app-skeleton is working fine. Must be something downstream in your code.

Comment: the problem is that iris does not depend on date that is why this example is not that good.

Comment: This is Beautiful! But it does not output any filtred data

Comment: You question was *how to use `input$dateRange[1]` and `input$dateRange[2]` in a render function* - this was what I was showing in the first place. Next time ask a more precise question and provide a proper *reproducible* example. I updated my answer once again.

Comment: Thank you very much.In fact i just used used the solution before the last update and added paste() .it works very well.The only problem is that when i update date range my data will be filtred based oh the input$rangedate[1] and all the data of the moths after that untill input$rangedate[2] are not there. I will poste my code.